# Divisible totally ordered additive abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, ordered-groups, divisible-groups

Let $(G,+,\leq)$ be a divisible totally ordered additive abelian group and $g_{1},g_{2}\in G$. If for every integer $n>1$,  $g_{1}\geq (1-\frac{1}{n})g_{2}$, Can we have $g_{1}\geq g_{2}$? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $G=\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ with the lexicographic order $(a,b)\le (c,d)\iff a<c$ or $(a=c)\land (b\le d)$.
Here viewing the first coordinate as the ordinary rational numbers, $\varepsilon:=(0,1)$ will behave like an infinitesimal: it's positive but less than $\frac1n(1,0)$ for every $n\ge 1$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Your example failing the above implication has rank>1 (rank of G is the order type of the set of proper convex subgroups of G ). I think if G is of rank one, the implication is satisfied?